# Rank of the quotient of an Abelian group by its torsion part?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-group, torsion-groups

Let $G$ be an Abelian group, and let $G_T$ be the torsion part of $G$.  Then my question is, does the rank of $G$ always equal the rank of the quotient group $\frac{G}{G_T}$?  Or can they differ in rank?

If they’re not equal in general, are there special cases that guarantee them to be equal?

Comment: For a finitely generated abelian group?

Comment: @Bernard Are they not equal in the general case?  If so which is greater than or equal to which?

Comment: How do you define the rank, if the group is not finitely generated?

Comment: @Bernard As the cardinality of a maximal linearly independent subset of $G$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group

Comment: Yes, but for finitely generated groups, the torsion subgroup has interesting properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, it is the same.**  I found the answer in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group#Definition):

> The set of all torsion elements is a subgroup, called the torsion subgroup and denoted T(A). A group is called torsion-free if it has no non-trivial torsion elements. The factor-group A/T(A) is the unique maximal torsion-free quotient of A and its rank coincides with the rank of A.