# Quotient of an abelian group by torsion subgroup provides a characteristic free abelian subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-group, torsion-groups

I have a follow up to this question: [Rank of the quotient of an Abelian group by its torsion part?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933583/rank-of-the-quotient-of-an-abelian-group-by-its-torsion-part).

So my understanding is given a finitely generated abelian group $G$ and its torsion subgroup $T_G$ then $T_G$ is fully characteristic (preserved under all endomorphisms of $G$) and $G/T_G$ is free abelian with rank equal to $G$.

Does this mean $G/T_G$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$ which is of same rank as $G$ (more precisely the coset representatives of $T_G$ in $G/T_G$ is the subgroup $H \cong Z^n$)? Intuitively I'd say something like for any $g \in G$ that was not finite order, then any automorphism of $G$ must map $g$ to another element of infinite order as the torsion subgroup is fully characteristic and if $g$ was mapped to a finite order element it was contradict that.

I'm not sure how to go about it from here. I feel like from the perspective of the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups where $G \cong \mathbb{Z}^n \times \mathbb{Z}_{k_1} \times \dots$ then $G/T_G$ would be the free abelian portion, and it would be characteristic. I'm struggling to formalise it however, I also wasn't able to find much on this so I feel like I may be missing something completely.

Comment: $G/T_G$ is not a subgroup of $G.$ And the elements of infinite order in $\Bbb Z^n\times\dots$ are not only the elements of the subgroup $\Bbb Z^n\times0.$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second part? What elements of $G$ which is not in the free abelian portion is in the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}^n \times 0$?

Comment: Also does the coset representatives of $T_G$ of $G$ not form a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Say $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}$. Then $(1,1)$ is not torsion, but not in $\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}$. The torsion subgroup is well defined, and it has a complement, but the complement is not unique.  So whole you can talk about **the** torsion subgroup, you cannot talk about "the torsionfree part". And any particular choice is not usually characteristic.In the example above, the automorphism sending $(1,0)$to itself and $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$does not map the $\mathbb{Z}$ factor to itself.

Comment: And there is no "the" coset representatives unless the torsion subgroup is trivial. You can choose a set of coset representatives that form. group, but the choice is not unique. And even such a choice is not invariant unless the torsion group is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that in a finitely generated abelian group $G$, the elements of finite order form a characteristic subgroup, called the torsion subgroup $T_G$.

But $G / T_G$ is not a subgroup of $G$. How could it be? Each element of a subgroup of $G$ is also an element of $G$ itself, but each element of $G / T_G$ is a coset of $T_G$ which is a certain subset of $G$. An element of $G$ and a subset of $G$ are two different set theoretical objects and cannot be equal to each other.

In the comments you also asked whether the coset representatives of $T_G$ form a subgroup. That question does not quite make sense because coset representatives are not unique. Nonetheless it is true is that coset representatives of the torsion subgroup ***can be chosen*** so as to form a subgroup. For example, assuming that
$$G = \mathbb Z^n \times (\mathbb Z_{i_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb Z_{i_k})
$$
it follows that the subgroup $Z^n \times \{0\}$ consists of coset representatives of the torsion subgroup (where $0$ denotes the identity element of the torsion subgroup $\mathbb Z_{i_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb Z_{i_k}$).

However, that subgroup $\mathbb Z^n \times \{0\}$ is not always characteristic.

One obtains a counterexample from the very simplest case of an infinite, finitely generated abelian group with nontrivial torsion, namely the group
$$G = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_2
$$
For elements of $\mathbb Z_2$ let me use the notation $[i] = i + 2 \mathbb Z \in \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z_2$. Then the subgroup $\mathbb Z \times \{[0]\}$ is not characteristic because that subgroup is not taken to itself by the automorphism $\phi : \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_2 \to \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_2$ that is defined by the formula
$$\phi(m,[n]) = (m,[n+m])
$$
Notice in particular: $\phi(1,[0])=(1,[1])$ has infinite order but is not contained in $\mathbb Z \times \{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks, the example helps a lot. What about the subgroup $G^t = \{g^t | g \in G \}$, where $t$ is the torsion exponent or $\{ tg | g \in G \}$ in additive notation. I believe it's characteristic in the rank 1 example (say $phi: (1,0) \mapsto 2,1$) would not be an automorphism. Would it be characteristic in general for f.g abelian groups though?

Comment: @Txim In an abelian group, the set of $k$th powers is always a subgroup and always fully characteristic for every fixed $k$. In an arbitrary group, the subgroup generated by all $k$th powers is also fully characteristic (in fact, it is a verbal subgroup).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks so much, this is the first time I've heard of the term verbal subgroups so thanks for that too